# pthreads in C - pthread_exit

Tags: c, pthreads

For some reason I thought that calling `pthread_exit(NULL)` at the end of a main function would guarantee that all running threads (at least created in the main function) would finish running before `main` could exit. However when I run this code below without calling the two `pthread_join` functions (at the end of `main`) explicitly I get a segmentation fault, which seems to happen because the `main` function has been exited before the two threads finish their job, and therefore the *char buffer* is not available anymore. However when I include these two `pthread_join` function calls at the end of `main` it runs as it should. To guarantee that `main` will not exit before all running threads have finished, is it necessary to call `pthread_join` explicitly for all threads initialized directly in `main`?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define NUM_CHAR 1024
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; 
    sem_t full;
    sem_t empty;
    char* buffer;
} Context;

void *Reader(void* arg) {
    Context* context = (Context*) arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHAR; ++i) {
        sem_wait(&context->full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(context->mutex));
        char c = context->buffer[i % BUFFER_SIZE];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(context->mutex));
        sem_post(&context->empty);

        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *Writer(void* arg) {
    Context* context = (Context*) arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHAR; ++i) {
        sem_wait(&context->empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(context->mutex));
        context->buffer[i % BUFFER_SIZE] = 'a' + (rand() % 26);
        float ranFloat = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        if (ranFloat < 0.5) sleep(0.2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(context->mutex));
        sem_post(&context->full);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    pthread_t reader, writer;
    Context context;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int status = 0;
    status = pthread_mutex_init(&context.mutex, NULL);
    status = sem_init(&context.full,0,0);
    status = sem_init(&context.empty,0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    context.buffer = buffer;

    status = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, Reader, &context);
    status = pthread_create(&writer, NULL, Writer, &context);

    pthread_join(reader,NULL);   // This line seems to be necessary
    pthread_join(writer,NULL);   // This line seems to be necessary

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

If that is the case, how could I handle the case where plenty of identical threads (like in the code below) would be created using the same thread identifier? In that case, how can I make sure that all the threads will have finished before `main` exits? Do I really have to keep an array of `NUM_STUDENTS pthread_t` identifiers to be able to do this? I guess I could do this by letting the Student threads signal a semaphore and then let the `main` function wait on that semaphore, but is there really no easier way to do this?

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,Student,NULL);  // Threads 
    // Make sure that all student threads have finished
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that `sleep()` takes an integer argument; your `sleep(0.2)` is equivalent to `sleep(0)` because of the implicit conversion.  If you need a sub-second sleep interval, use (POSIX standard) [nanosleep()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html).

Answer (score 18):

`pthread_exit()` is a function called by a thread to terminate its own execution.  For the situation you've given it is not to be called from your main program thread.

As you have figured out, `pthread_join()` is the correct means to wait for the completion of a joinable thread from `main()`.

Also as you've figured out, you need to maintain the value returned from `pthread_create()` to pass to `pthread_join()`.

What this means is that you cannot use the same `pthread_t` variable for all the threads you create if you intend to use `pthread_join()`.

Rather, build an array of `pthread_t` so that you have a copy of each thread's ID.

Comment: Can you quote an authority for your statement '[i]t is never to be called from your main program thread'?

Comment: @Jonathan:  It is certainly not authoritative.  Rather it is just advice for someone new to pthreads.  Perhaps my language comes across the wrong way.  I'll adjust it.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Everything I have ever read on pthread_exit() suggests the exact opposite of this post; that pthread_exit() should indeed be the last call in main. "By having main() explicitly call pthread_exit() as the last thing it does, main() will block and be kept alive to support the threads it created until they are done." See: [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) or [Creating and Terminating Threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads).

Comment: What you are missing is the fact that his main() cannot exit before his threads due to resources being allocated in main()'s stack and used in the threads.  If main() goes out of scope before the threads there will be a process crash.  If that were not true, then pthread_exit() could be used prior to the threads terminating.  The main thread destroys its stack before blocking in pthread_exit().

Answer (score 4):

Quite aside from whether the program should or should not terminate when the main thread calls `pthread_exit`, `pthread_exit` says

> The pthread_exit() function terminates
>   the calling thread

And also:

> After a thread has terminated, the
>   result of access to local (auto)
>   variables of the thread is undefined.

Since the context is an automatic variable of `main()`, your code can fall over before it even gets to the point of testing what you want it to test...

Comment: Exactly.  The OP could fix the problem by declaring `Context` and `buffer` with static storage duration.

Comment: Or better yet, by allocating them with `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

## A mini saga

You don't mention the environment in which you are running the original code.  I modified your code to use [`nanosleep()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) (since, as I mentioned in a comment to the question, `sleep()` takes an integer and therefore `sleep(0.2)` is equivalent to `sleep(0)`), and compiled the program on MacOS X 10.6.4.

### Without error checking

It works fine; it took about 100 seconds to run with the 0.5 probability factor (as you'd expect; I changed that to 0.05 to reduce the runtime to about 10 seconds), and generated a random string - some of the time.

Sometimes I got nothing, sometimes I got more and sometimes I got less data.  But I didn't see a core dump (not even with 'ulimit -c unlimited' to allow arbitrarily large core dumps).

Eventually, I applied some tools and got to see that I always got 1025 characters (1024 generated plus a newline), but quite often, I got 1024 ASCII NUL characters.  Sometimes they'd appear in the middle, sometimes at the beginning, etc:

```
$  ./pth | tpipe -s "vis | ww -w64" "wc -c"
    1025
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000ocriexffwgdvdvyfitjtvlzcoffhusjo
zyacniffpsfswesgrkuxycsubufamxxzkrkqnwvsxcbmktodessyohixsmuhdovt
hhertqjjinzoptcuqzertybicrzaeyqlyublbfgutcdvftwkuvxhouiuduoqrftw
xjkgqutpryelzuaerpsbotwyskaflwofseibfqntecyseufqxvzikcyeeikjzsye
qxhjwrjmunntjwhohqovpwcktolcwrvmfvdfsmkvkrptjvslivbfjqpwgvroafzn
fkjumqxjbarelbrdijfrjbtiwnajeqgnobjbksulvcobjkzwwifpvpmpwyzpwiyi
cdpwalenxmocmtdluzouqemmjdktjtvfqwbityzmronwvulfizpizkiuzapftxay
obwsfajcicvcrrjehjeyzsngrwusbejiovaaatyzouktetcerqxjsdpswixjpege
blxscdebfsptxwvwsllvydipovzmnrvoiopmqotydqaujwdykidmwzitdsropguv
vudyfiaaaqueyllnwudfpplcfbsngqqeyucdawqxqzczuwsnaquofreilzvdwbjq
ksrouwltvaktpdrvjnqahpdqdshmmvntspglexggshqbjrvxceaqlfnukedxzlms
cnapdtgtcoyhnglojbjnplowericrzbfulvrobfn
$
```

(The 'tpipe' program is like 'tee' but it writes to pipes instead of files (and to standard output unless you specify the '-s' option); 'vis' comes from 'The UNIX Programming Environment' by Kernighan & Pike; 'ww' is a 'word wrapper' but there aren't any words here so it brute force wraps at width 64.)

The behaviour I was seeing was highly indeterminate - I'd get different results on each run.  I even replaced the random characters with the alphabet in sequence ('a' + i % 26), and was still getting odd behaviour.

I added some debug printing code (and a counter to the contex), and it was clear that the semaphore `context->full` was not working properly for the reader - it was being allowed to go into the mutual exclusion before the writer had written anything.

### With error checking

When I added error checking to the mutex and semaphore operations, I found that:

```
sem_init(&context.full) failed (-1)
errno = 78 (Function not implemented)
```

So, the weird outputs are because MacOS X does not implement `sem_init()`.  It's odd; the `sem_wait()` function failed with errno = 9 (EBADF 'Bad file descriptor'); I added the checks there first.  Then I checked the initialization...

### Using sem_open() instead of sem_init()

The `sem_open()` calls succeed, which looks good (names `"/full.sem"` and `"/empty.sem"`, flags O_CREAT, mode  values of 0444, 0600, 0700 at different times, and initial values 0 and BUFFER_SIZE, as with `sem_init()`).  Unfortunately, the first `sem_wait()` or `sem_post()` operation fails with errno = 9 (EBADF 'Bad file descriptor') again.

### Morals

- It is important to check error conditions from system calls.
- The output I see is non-deterministic because the semaphores don't work.
- That doesn't alter the 'it does not crash without the `pthread_join()` calls' behaviour.
- MacOS X does not have a working POSIX semaphore implementation.

Comment: Generally, the `sem_t` functions may be interrupted by signal handlers (e.g I/O) and it may have `EINTR` in `errno` in that case. So yes, you should capture the error of *all* `sem_t` functions, regardless which interface you chose to create them.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_join()` is the standard way to wait for the other thread to complete, I would stick to that.

Alternatively, you can create a thread counter and have all child threads increment it by 1 at start, then decrement it by 1 when they finish (with proper locking of course), then have your `main()` wait for this counter to hit 0. (`pthread_cond_wait()` would be my choice).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for calling `pthread_join(reader,NULL);` at all if `Context` and `buffer` are declared with static storage duration (as already pointed out by Steve Jessop, caf and David Schwartz).

Declaring `Context` and `buffer` static also makes it necessary to change `Context *context` to `Context *contextr` or `Context *contextw` respectively.

In addition, the following rewrite called `pthread_exit.c` replaces `sem_init()` with `sem_open()` and uses `nanosleep()` (as suggested by Jonathan Leffler).

`pthread_exit` was tested on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and did not output any ASCII NUL characters.

```
/*

cat pthread_exit.c  (sample code to test pthread_exit() in main())

source: 
"pthreads in C - pthread_exit",
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330048/pthreads-in-c-pthread-exit

compiled on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with:
gcc -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu99 -Os -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual  -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wmissing-prototypes -Wformat=2 -l pthread -o pthread_exit pthread_exit.c

test with: 
time -p bash -c './pthread_exit | tee >(od -c 1>&2) | wc -c'

*/


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include <time.h>

void *Reader(void* arg);
void *Writer(void* arg);

// #define NUM_CHAR 1024
#define NUM_CHAR 100
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; 
    sem_t *full;
    sem_t *empty;
    const char *semname1;
    const char *semname2;
    char* buffer;
} Context;


static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static Context context;

void *Reader(void* arg) {
    Context *contextr = (Context*) arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHAR; ++i) {
        sem_wait(contextr->full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(contextr->mutex));
        char c = contextr->buffer[i % BUFFER_SIZE];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(contextr->mutex));
        sem_post(contextr->empty);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *Writer(void* arg) {
    Context *contextw = (Context*) arg;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHAR; ++i) {
        sem_wait(contextw->empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(contextw->mutex));
        contextw->buffer[i % BUFFER_SIZE] = 'a' + (rand() % 26);
        float ranFloat = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        //if (ranFloat < 0.5) sleep(0.2);
        if (ranFloat < 0.5)
           nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 200000000L}}, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(contextw->mutex));
        sem_post(contextw->full);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t reader, writer;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int status = 0;
    status = pthread_mutex_init(&context.mutex, NULL);
    context.semname1 = "Semaphore1";
    context.semname2 = "Semaphore2";

    context.full = sem_open(context.semname1, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    if (context.full == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "ERROR creating semaphore semname1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    context.empty = sem_open(context.semname2, O_CREAT, 0777, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (context.empty == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "ERROR creating semaphore semname2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    context.buffer = buffer;

    status = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, Reader, &context);
    status = pthread_create(&writer, NULL, Writer, &context);

//    pthread_join(reader,NULL);   // This line seems to be necessary
//    pthread_join(writer,NULL);   // This line seems to be necessary

    sem_unlink(context.semname1);
    sem_unlink(context.semname2);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_join` does the following :

> The `pthread_join()` function suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has already terminated. On return from a successful `pthread_join()` call with a non-NULL `value_ptr` argument, the value passed to `pthread_exit()` by the terminating thread is made available in the location referenced by `value_ptr`. When a `pthread_join()` returns successfully, the target thread has been terminated. The results of multiple simultaneous calls to `pthread_join()` specifying the same target thread are undefined. If the thread calling `pthread_join()` is canceled, then the target thread will not be detached.

However you can achieve the same by using a light weight loop which will prevent the `exe` from exiting. In Glib this is achieved by creating a [GMainLoop](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html), in Gtk+ you can use the [gtk_main](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-General.html#gtk-main).
After completion of threads you have to quit the main loop or call `gtk_exit`.

Alternatively you can create you own wait functionality using a combination of sockets,pipes and select system call but this is not required and can be considered as an exercise for practice.

Answer (score 0):

Per normal `pthread` semantics, as taught e.g. [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads), your original idea does seem to be confirmed:

> If main() finishes before the threads
>   it has created, and exits with
>   pthread_exit(), the other threads will
>   continue to execute. Otherwise, they
>   will be automatically terminated when
>   main() finishes.

However I'm not sure whether that's part of the POSIX threads *standard* or just a common but not universal "nice to have" add-on tidbit (I do know that some implementations don't respect this constraint -- I just don't know whether those implementations are nevertheless to be considered standard compliant!-).  So I'll have to join the prudent chorus recommending the joining of every thread you need to terminate, just to be on the safe side -- or, as Jon Postel [put it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) in the context of TCP/IP implementations:

```
Be conservative in what you send; be liberal in what you accept.
```

a "principle of robustness" that should be used way more broadly than just in TCP/IP;-).

Comment: The problem here isn't that the other threads aren't continuing to execute - they are - it's that the data they need has been destroyed, since it was declared as `auto` variables in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`pthread_exit(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_exit/) exits the thread that calls it (but not the whole process if other threads are still running). In your example other threads use variables on `main`'s stack, thus when `main`'s thread exits and its stack is destroyed they access unmapped memory, thus the segfault.

Use proper [`pthread_join(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/) technique as suggested by others, or move shared variables into static storage.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a thread a pointer to a variable, you need to ensure that the lifetime of that variable is at least as long as the thread will attempt to access that variable. You pass the threads pointers to `buffer` and `context`, which are allocated on the stack inside `main`. As soon as `main` exits, those variables cease to exist. So you cannot exit from `main` until you confirm that those threads no longer need access to those pointers.

95% of the time, the fix for this problem is to follow this simple pattern:

> 1) Allocate an object to hold the parameters.
>
> 2) Fill in the object with the parameters.
>
> 3) Pass a pointer to the object to the new thread.
>
> 4) Allow the new thread to deallocate the object.

Sadly, this doesn't work well for objects shared by two or more threads. In that case, you can put a use count and a mutex inside the parameter object. Each thread can decrement the use count under protection of the mutex when it's done. The thread that drops the use count to zero frees the object.

You would need to do this for both `buffer` and `context`. Set the use count to `2` and then pass a pointer to this object to both threads.